# Angular - How to get data from subscribed service few times and not overwrite previous results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have a service which has following method:

room-service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class RoomService {
  private readonly _equipment: BehaviorSubject<EquipmentDto[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public equipment$ = this._equipment.asObservable();

  getEquipmentForRoom(roomId: number) {
    this.restService.getEquipmentForRoom(roomId).subscribe(res => {
      this._equipment.next(res);
    });
  }
```

room-component.ts:

```js
@Component()
export class RoomsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() room: RoomEntity;
  equipment$: Observable < EquipmentDto[] > ;
  equipmentList: Array < EquipmentDto > ;

  constructor(private equipmentService: EquipmentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.equipment$ = this.equipmentService.equipment$;
      this.equipmentService.getEquipmentForRoom(this.room.id);

      this.equipment$.subscribe(items => {
        this.equipmentList = items;
      });
```

room-component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let eq of room.equipmentList">
    <!-- list my equipment here -->
</div>
```

Now I have a parent component which contains multiple Room Components (those are added programmatically based on the amount of rooms). Anyway, list of equipment is the same for each of the rooms. It looks like once subscribed, the data in first components is overwritten by the component created as the last one.

**My question is, how can I get a proper data for each of the rooms using the observable from my service?**

Comment: Apart from the solution. Why is the roomservice so complex. Wouldn't this line be enough?: public equipment$ = this.restService.getEquipmentForRoom(roomId);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach with single BehaviorSubject only when your data is the only source of this data.

Instead, you can change your `getEquipmentForRoom(roomId: number)` like this:

```
getEquipmentForRoom(roomId: number) {
    return this.restService.getEquipmentForRoom(roomId);
}
```

And then subscribe to it in the compoment:

```
this.equipmentService.getEquipmentForRoom(this.room.id).subscribe(items => {
  this.equipmentList = items;
});
```

And I agree with Alexander, this component should be dumb as possible.

Answer (score 1):

try to build pipes instead of subscriptions

```js
@Injectable()    
export class RoomService {
      // return an observable.
      getEquipmentForRoom$(roomId: number) {
        return this.restService.getEquipmentForRoom(roomId);
      }
```

```js
@Component()
export class RoomsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() room: RoomEntity;
  equipment$: Observable<EquipmentDto[]>;

  constructor(private equipmentService: EquipmentService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    // simply share observable.
    this.equipment$ = this.equipmentService.getEquipmentForRoom$(this.room.id);
  });
```

```html
  <div *ngFor="let eq of equipment$ | async"> <!-- add async here -->
      <!-- list my equipment here -->
  </div>
```

Comment: That resolved my problem. Anyway I need to conditionally check if equipment$ contains any items, and I am not sure if it is possible to check on async

Comment: Yep, async reacts on every emit. If you want to call `getEquipmentForRoom$(this.room.id)` itself you can use `takeUntil` and `repeat` with an interval you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data once in your parent and pass the data to your child components.
That child component (RoomsComponent) should be dumb and not doing requests

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto **Alexander**’s answer.

The problem is that you are subscribing to the same `BehaviourSubject` for all the components and the components are taking the latest `roomData` that is emitted by the `BehaviourSubject`, which would be the last `RoomComponent`.

It would work if the `BehaviuorSubject` holds all the rooms which are fetched by the parent component, and passing each room data to each RoomComponent using `@Input`.